# Can't run a vm in Hyper-V on a Windows 2016 vm

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2016

I am on a vm running Windows server 2016. I am unable to run docker because of Hyper-V won't start any vms I create. I have enabled nested vms on the Server 2016 vm thru the VSphere web client.
When attempting to start docker, get this error:

```
Unable to start: The running command stopped because the preference 
variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: 
'MobyLinuxVM' failed to start.

The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to start the virtual 
machine 'MobyLinuxVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not 
running (Virtual machine ID A346B28D-1AC1-4297-BE7E-6C002627EE0D).
at Start-MobyLinuxVM, <No file>: line 315
```

Hyper-V won't start any vms I create.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i solved it by setting the type of OS della VM as "Hyper-V" in Vmware fusion.
Hope it helps
Danilo